# Squarespace metadata formatting

Tags: javascript, html, metadata, squarespace, author

I’m currently creating a website (private at the moment) in Squarespace using the Bedford template.

What I’d like to do is learn to create advanced formatting of a metadata item (for example, a blog "author").  However, in my case the formatting would only occur once the metadata item is clicked and opens up as a new page that contains the summary of associated items (in my case, a list of blog posts).

The link here (https://support.squarespace.com/hc/en-us/articles/217472887-Author-profiles) opens an example of the Skye template.  If you scroll about halfway down the page, you’ll see an example for "author filtered pages".  The metadata item = author name.  Note that it says "all by display name". That's pretty much the format of what I'm trying to obtain - but using the Bedford template.   The author filtered page format for Bedford is pretty minimal and only shows the author name (in the Bedford template, it's missing "all by ...", missing the author photo, and isn't centered on the page).

I've found absolutely no information about formatting the metadata summary page - including choosing where the metadata item name goes on a page, whether or not I can add a thumbnail image, how to add addition text (for example, "all posts by ..." and then the “author name”), etc.   It seems further complicated as the summary page only exists once you’ve clicked the metadata item, so I don’t know where the code should go.

If you can help with this coding, I’d also be interested to learn how to have a Bedford-style banner behind the formatted metadata author name.